# What is the meaning of expression "+ + a"?

Tags: c

When there is a space between `+ +`, what is meaning of expression "`+ + a`".  How is this expression evaluated?

```
    int main()
    {
        int a = 3;

        printf("%d %d", + +a, a);
    }
```

and also how is `a+++a` evaluated?
Is it undefined or unspecified or implementation defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is a space in the middle in the `++` operator, then you are just applying the unary plus operator twice.

About the expression `a+++a`, 
the C specification says that when there is such an ambiguity, munch as much as possible (the
"greedy lexer" or "maximal munch" rule). So `a+++a` is evaluated as `a++ + a`

According to that rule, an expression like, `z = y+++++x;`
will be parsed as `z = y++ ++ +x;`, which is invalid (the result of a post-increment is not itself incrementable).

Comment: Also known, somewhat more euphonically, as the 'Maximal Munch' rule.

Comment: Note that when there is a space between two `+` symbols, it is not an increment operator; it is two separate `+` operators.  By definition, you cannot have a space in a `++` operator.

Answer (score 8):

It is a no-op — twice because `+ a` is a no-op and it is repeated.

`a+++a` is unambiguously parsed as `a++ + a`, but leads to undefined behaviour when executed.

Note that if the code set `a = -3;`, the value printed would still be `-3`, twice.

Comment: Just a nitpick, `+` is not always a nop, it may also force a conversion to a wider type.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Is there a context in which the presence of the unary `+` would force the change where the change would not occur in the absence of the unary `+`?  Off-hand, I can't think of one.  In the `printf()` example, if `a` were a `char` or `short`, the conversion to `int` would occur regardless of whether the `+` was there (because of the rules for treating varargs arguments).  If there was an assignment such as `a = +a;`, there might nominally be a conversion from say `char` to `int` on the RHS, but the assignment would reduce that back again, and the same would apply to `a = a;`.

Answer (score 1):

`+a` is just the opposite of `-a`.
In otherwords, where `-a` would have the opposite sign of `a`, `+a` just re-affirms the existing positive/negative sign of `a`.

Then there's an outer positive again, still resulting in 3.

The opposite version would be:

```
printf("%d %d",- -a,a);
```

Which would be "negative-negative 3"... which is again `+3`.

Comment: Given: `a = -3;`, `b = +a;` is not the same as `b = abs(a);`.  In the first case, `b` is `-3`; in the second (`abs()`) case, it is `+3`.

Comment: Hmm never thought about it but I don't think +a is the opposite of -a since, +a will always be positive regardless of value of a, but -a can be either positive or negative i.e. two negs make positive but two positives are also positive... just sayin.

Comment: Will +a be always positive? I don't think so. Mathemathically, +(-3) is _still_ -3...

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that +a was at all like `abs`  (and I did not write that).  `+a` just tautologically re-affirms the existing sign that `a` already has.

Comment: OK — I'm relieved that isn't what you thought.  I'm worried that your answer gave the opposite impression.